# Adding a new layer to a stax.serial object

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, jax

I'd like to "convert" the following tensorflow code in jax:

```
def mlp(L, n_list, activation, Cb, Cw):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    kernel_initializers_list = []
    kernel_initializers_list.append(tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(0, math.sqrt(Cw/n_list[0])))
    for l in range(1, L): 
        kernel_initializers_list.append(tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(0, math.sqrt(Cw/n_list[l])))
    kernel_initializers_list.append(tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(0, math.sqrt(Cw/n_list[L])))
    bias_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=math.sqrt(Cb))


    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_list[1], input_shape=[n_list[0]], use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializers_list[0],
          bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
    for l in range(1, L): 
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_list[l+1], activation=activation, use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializers_list[l],
              bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_list[L+1], use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializers_list[L],
              bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

In jax can I add a `stax.Dense` to the thing I get calling `stax.serial()` with something equivalent to tensorflow's `model.add()`? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
#Create new model by jax
net_init, net_apply = stax.serial(
    Conv(32, (3, 3), padding='SAME'),
    Relu,
    Conv(64, (3, 3), padding='SAME'),
    Relu,
    Conv(128, (3, 3), padding='SAME'),
    Relu,
    Conv(256, (3, 3), padding='SAME'),
    Relu,
    MaxPool((2, 2)),
    Flatten,
    Dense(128),
    Relu,
    Dense(10),
    LogSoftmax,
)

net_init(random.PRNGKey(111), input_shape=(-1, 32, 32, 3))    

#Feedfoward
inputs, targets = batch_data
net_apply(params, inputs)
```

This is my [reference](https://www.kaggle.com/code/aakashnain/building-models-in-jax-part1-stax#Model) to help you.

Comment: I don't think this answer to my question: I'm searching for a way (if there is one) for adding a Dense() after the execution of stax.serial().

Comment: There is no option to do that in a direct way. From the Jax docs, they say, "Stax is a small but flexible neural net specification library from scratch. You likely do not mean to import this module! Stax is intended as an example library only. There are a number of other much more fully-featured neural network libraries for JAX, including Flax from Google, and Haiku from DeepMind."

Comment: Nevertheless, if you want to do that, put the output of serial nn into the new Dense. This is an indirect way, so I think that it maybe bothersome to build the construction. Not a good idea. In addition, you can understand why they name the library as jax.example_libraries.stax